# How to get content from a dynamic webpage

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, ios7

recently, I am developing an iOS app that want to get the content from a dynamic webpage.

Here is what I want to do:

http://www.ratemycoopjob.com

For the website above, I want to get ratings for employers I searched. The question is this page is a dynamic page, some javascript code will be called once search. I cannot treat this page as a static html file and parse it.

Comment: you should check if this site offers an API you can use, because scraping a site is invariably against the site's TOS.

Comment: Not to mention parsing HTML for data is generally a terrible idea in the first place.

Comment: Yep, look at the last clause of the ToS. I'd contact them and see if they're receptive to your offer to develop an iOS front-end. If so, they might provide a JSON/XML based interface. In practical reality, these sorts of sites are not always receptive to these sorts of inquiries (they'd generally like to control the interface, so that they're collecting the appropriate data to make this commercially viable), but it's worth checking.

Comment: Thank you guys' advices! I've contact them but haven't received any replies, so that's why I have this idea to get the information. I'll continue to contact them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse an HTML in iOS, you could try HtmlParser of Ben Reeves (https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser)

But first, you have to collect data from that site, generally by using REST service: POST/GET with right parameters or having the APIs

Edit: sorry, I did not read carefully your question. In case of JS, you can create an UIWebView, load this site into that view, then use

```
NSString *returnvalue = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"your javascript code string here"];
```

to get new content after affected a javascript on this site. However, you have to know about java script function of that site.

Good lucks